# How to detect a new component is loaded in app component or in common place?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I am using angular with ionic framework. And to navigate from one component to other I am using ionic nav controller.
All I want is whichever component is loaded, it gives the name of that component at a common place or in app component

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global service with rxjs subject to track any component activity like created, destroy or others

*TrackerService*

```
@Injectable({providedIn:"root"}) //  root
export class TrackerService {

  private _sub = new Subject();
  constructor() { }

  public post(data:any) { //  send a data to subscriber 
    this._sub.next(data)
  }

  public subscribe(fx:any) : Subscription {  //  tracker activity 
    return this._sub.subscribe(fx);
  }

}
```

in any component just inject the tracker server and post a data at any case init , destroy  or maybe at some cases like login ...

as example

```
  constructor(private _tracker:TrackerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._tracker.post({message:'FirstComponent is active'}); // send 
  }

  ngOnDestroy() { 
    this._tracker.post({message:'FirstComponent is deactive'});

  }
```

and I have subscribe to the tracker service at app component like this

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this._tracker.subscribe(result => console.log(result)); // arrived 

  }
```

> tracker subscribe method return a **subscription** object so you can
>   unsubscribe later

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zga2eb)

Comment: In this solution, I have to subscribe the Subject in every component. And I have more than 100 components in my application. I want a solution like http interceptors. Whenever a component gets loaded, it calls the interceptor automatically and give info. Or may be before the component loading.

Comment: you subscribe once and inject the service in all component same way I did with the app.component , you only need to `subscribe` once if you compoennt global like app.component

Comment: you can store the result in global object as keyvalue class/boolean and check the component sate in my example I just log the result so you can know if the component is loader but againe you just need to subscribe once to tracke all this action 

Comment: still I need to inject the service in every component. I was thinking for a solution on component boot loading. Before loading the component, it will resolve the component and tells that this component is going to load.